# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument | Datetime Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timestamp

Receiving following error when trying to convert an integer into datetime.

**ERROR**

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

**CODE**

```
from datetime import datetime

anewvalue = [20210805180238, 20210805180239, 20210805180241]

timestamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(anewvalue[1]))
print(timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

**CODE EXPLANATION**

- Importing `datetime` module.
- Initializing an array.
- Passing array to datetime.
- Converting into timestamp.

**NOTE**

It works fine when I pass custom integer.

Comment: I get `ValueError: year 642424 is out of range` from your code

Comment: convert to string and parse like `datetime.strptime(str(20210805180238), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")`

Comment: I suggest you review the datetime.fromtimestamp() documentation where you will clearly see the error of your ways

Comment: @MrFuppes datetime.strptime(str(20210805180238), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S") it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used this solution to solve it:

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
d=datetime.fromtimestamp(0) + timedelta(milliseconds=t)
```

*t: timestamp in ms*

It should work for you.

M

Comment: the OP's input obviously aren't milliseconds since the UNIX epoch. Instead, the integer datatyp is used to represent a certain date/time *format*, see my comment under the question.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Thanks!